# build a nested array from multiple axios requests on Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, request, axios

I'm new to Vuejs, I can't figure out how to build a nested array from 2 axios request, I know that there is a better method to achieve the goal... with this code I build 2 separate array, one for  productList (with all products of the single shop) and one for shopName (with all shop_urls). I need to use array.map for nested request because I want to build a array of products foreach shop_url

```
import axios from 'axios';

    export default 
    {
        name: 'Product',

        data: () => ({
            key: 'mySecretKey',
            productsList: [],
            shopName: [],
            errors: [],
        }),

          mounted() {
            axios.get('https://shop.domain.org/api/shop_urls?display=full&output_format=JSON', {                
                auth: {
                    username: this.key
                },
        }) 
        .then(response => response.data.shop_urls.map((val) => {
            this.shopName.push(val.virtual_uri)
            axios.get('https://shop.domain.org/' + val.virtual_uri + '/api/products?display=full&output_format=JSON', {                
                auth: {
                    username: this.key
                },
            })
            .then(response => this.productsList.push(response.data.products))
            .catch(e => this.errors.push(e))

        }))
    }
}
```

response:
[image]

Comment: Isnt possible to handle it in server side to prevent send request twice ? response of server side can be array of objects like `{ 'val' : val, 'products':  products }`

Comment: nope maybe, is the prestashop API webservice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that you could use

```
this.$set(this.productsList, val.virtual_uri, response.data.products)
```

That would create

```
productsList: [
    "whateverthevirtualuriwas": [
        ...response.data.products
    ]
]
```

Hard to say without knowing a little more about how the data arrives and how you're using it, but hopefully this is helpful.

***responding to question edit***
Okay, no need to put shopName and productsList into data imo. Just the merged array.

```js
// in your data: mergedArray: [ ]

for (let index in shopName) {
    const uri = shopName[index]
    const products = productList[index]

    this.$set(this.mergedArray, uri, products)
}
```

Comment: Edited to match.

Comment: thank u mate, with your help I figure out like this:

`.then(response => this.productsList.push({name: val.virtual_uri, items: response.data.products}))`